# Optimize nodejs mysql insertion

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb, query-optimization, sql-insert

I have been working on a ETL tool for mongodb to mysql conversion which is hosted on github here [mongodb-to-mysql-conversion](https://github.com/database-conversion/mongodb-to-mysql-conversion). Currently after conversion of the mongodb documents the insertion queries are sent for execution but the insertions speed is at max of 600 insertions per second. Is there a limit to insertion queries/sec in mysql for nodejs? if so then how to increase it? otherwise is there any framework that does not have this limitation? The code of whole conversion is at [main conversion code](https://github.com/database-conversion/mongodb-to-mysql-conversion/blob/master/app_with_conn_pool_1.js).

There is a limitation of creating arrays for insertion query as all the documents could contain different keys in them which will create difference in query column names.

Answer (score 1):

(Too long for a Comment)

I see a lot of "sleeps" in the code.  They are probably there for good reason, but may impact the insertion rate.

I see some code that apparently "batches" the rows to `INSERT` (into MySQL).  But it was not obvious how many are batched together.  100-1000 is somewhat optimal.  (One at a time would be 10x slower; beyond 1000 at a time is getting into "diminishing returns" *and* may hit inefficiencies related to large size.)

What is the batch size?

What is the total number of rows being transferred?

Are you sure that the slowdown is on MySQL's side, not Mongo's or NodeJs's?

The fact that the code here batches the inserts is encouraging.  But in my experience, many 'frameworks' fail to consider scaling beyond toy-sized projects.

Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  There are several things that *may* impact the insertion speed.

Advice on using key-value data in MySQL:  Don't pull out every possible column.  Pull out *only* the columns that are most important for searching and filtering; leave the rest in a JSON (or similar) column for the app to deal with.  More:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav

Comment: Currently the batchsize is 1000 for each node in cluster.
The reading from mongodb and parsing speed is very high. The bottleneck is mysql insertion. 
I am checking the insertions by manually executing the count query in mysql database.